# I can not get the shell command to launch a kill command from my phone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am writing an iPhone app for a Jailbroken IPhone.  From the app I want to kill an Apple Core Application like Safari or SMS Messaging.  I have tried a number methods:

1. `system("/usr/bin/killall AppName");`
2. `system("/bin/kill ProcessId");`
3. `NSString *exec = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/killall %@", @"AppName"];
       system([exec UTF8String]);`

I have shell access to my phone, and I have also tried setting the permissions and owner of my app so it runs as root with no luck.  I can use the kill and killall command from the shell when I am logged in as root.  Is there an Xcode/Objective C call that I can make to kill a Running IPhone App by Name or PID?  For this example/answer please use Safari as the Running App on the iPhone.

Comment: Did you get any further on this?